# Can't make 2 buttons play 2 different songs on my HTML

Tags: html, button

Firstly, I'm super (SUPER) new to coding in general. I'm doing a college project for a site, and I wanted to make a certain page have 2 buttons that play songs, 2 different versions, one for each button. I copied the code  from stack overflow, can't remember where but I'll be forever thankful for that one answer. I'm new to SO too so I hope I put the code here the right way :|

```
<!-- BTN1-->
    <button id="ASong" onClick="playPause()" >
  <audio
    src="mp3/Persona_5_OST-_Beneath_the_Mask_(getmp3.pro).mp3"
    autoplay
    loop
  ></audio>
   <img src="img/musica2.png" width="100px" align="left" margin-top="40px">
 <br/>
 
</button>

<script>
  var aud = document.getElementById("ASong").children[0];
  var isPlaying = false;
  aud.pause();

  function playPause() {
    if (isPlaying) {
      aud.pause();
    } else {
      aud.play();
    }
    isPlaying = !isPlaying;
  }
</script>
       <!-- BTN1-->
       
        <!-- BTN2-->
    <button id="ASong2" onClick="playPause()" >
  <audio
    src="mp3/Persona_5_OST_-_Beneath_the_Mask_r_(getmp3.pro).mp3"
    autoplay
    loop
  ></audio>
   <img src="img/musica2.png" width="100px" align="left" margin-top="40px">
 <br/>
 
</button>

<script>
  var aud = document.getElementById("ASong2").children[0];
  var isPlaying = false;
  aud.pause();

  function playPause() {
    if (isPlaying) {
      aud.pause();
    } else {
      aud.play();
    }
    isPlaying = !isPlaying;
  }
</script>
       <!-- BTN2-->
```

The only thing I really tried was changing the `ID` name for the second song. What happens is. I choose a button and click it first. That one button, with that specific song is the one that'll play (edit, it's not the first one I click, it's only one of the songs :/ it switched which one it was when I changed the ID name) , even if I try to press the other button afterwards. It's like both of them become the same button, they function the same. What I wanted is that each one of them worked separately. I want to be able to click, start one song, pause it, click on the other button and start the other song, which is not what's happening right now. I hope that makes sense D=

Comment: Despite being in 2 different `script` tags your second assignment to the `aud` variable will overwrite the first.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to modernize this a bit. Inline event handlers listeners are not the way to go these days. I'' use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead.

Next, I'm going to use one lot of code to handle the actions. One concept to get used to as you learn to program is DRY: Don't Repeat Yourself. To facilitate the state of your playback I'll use a [data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) on the button

```js
/*Get the buttons*/
document.querySelectorAll(".playPause").forEach(function(el) {
  /*Add a click event listener*/
  el.addEventListener("click", function() {
    /*Get the first audio tag in the clicked button*/
    var aud = this.querySelector("audio");
    /*Check the data attirbute on the button if playing*/
    if (this.dataset.isplaying === "true") {
      /*Debug line*/
      console.log("Pausing " + aud.src)
      /*Change the status of the data attribute*/
      this.dataset.isplaying = "false";
      /*Pause the audio element*/
      aud.pause();
    } else {
      /*Debug line*/
      console.log("Playing " + aud.src)
      /*Change the status of the data attribute*/
      this.dataset.isplaying = "true";
      /*PLay the audio element*/
      aud.play();
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<button id="ASong" class="playPause" data-isplaying="false">
  <audio
    src="mp3/Persona_5_OST-_Beneath_the_Mask_(getmp3.pro).mp3"
    autoplay
    loop
  ></audio>
   <img src="img/musica2.png" width="100px" align="left" margin-top="40px">
</button>
<button id="ASong2" class="playPause" data-isplaying="false">
  <audio
    src="mp3/Persona_5_OST_-_Beneath_the_Mask_r_(getmp3.pro).mp3"
    autoplay
    loop
  ></audio>
   <img src="img/musica2.png" width="100px" align="left" margin-top="40px">

</button>
```